# Retrive multiple index with element() function in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to **retrieve multiple resources ids with element function,** but I don't know how to proceed , here my a part of my exemple :

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "nsgs_asg-asg" {
  count                      = length(var.nsgrule_asg_asg)
  name                       = "name1"

#ASG source & destination
  source_application_security_group_ids = [element(
    azurerm_application_security_group.asg.*.id,
    var.nsgrule_asg_asg[count.index]["Id_source_asg"],
        )]
}
```

The objective is to be able to have a list for "**Id_source_asg**" (something like "1, 2, 4") and having the **element()** function retriving   :

- azurerm_application_security_group.asg.1.id ,
- azurerm_application_security_group.asg.2.id
- azurerm_application_security_group.asg.4.id
- and so on (can be a list 5 or 2 values ).

This is an example of my tfvars file :

```
nsgrule_asg_asg = [
    {
    ....
    rule_sufix = "rule1"
    nsg-rule_rg = "rgp-001"
    direction = "Inbound"
    priority = "xx"
    ...

    Id_source_asg = "0"
    ...
    },
]
```

and I have :

```
variable "nsgrule_asg_asg" {
  type = list(any)
}
```

I know the element fuction is working on the base **element(list, index)**.
I want to have multiple indexs, maybe I should had other functions before element()

In final the source_application_security_group_ids will be something like = "subscrptions/xxx/[...]/asg1,subscrptions/xxx/[...]/asg2,subscrptions/xxx/[...]/asg4" but without writing this.

Thanks and have a good day.

EDIT : Changing **source_application_security_group_ids**

```
source_application_security_group_ids = [for elem in var.nsgrule_asg_asg[count.index]["Id_source_asg"]: element(azurerm_application_security_group.asg.*.id, elem.Id_nsg)]
```

gives this error :

```
Iteration over non-iterable value [...] A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the variable `var.nsgrule_asg_asg`?

Comment: nsgrule_asg_asg = [
    {
    access = "Allow"
    rule_sufix = "app1"
    nsg-rule_rg = "rgp-xxx"
    direction = "Inbound"
    priority = "100"
    destination_port_range = "443"
    protocol = "tcp"
    source_port_range = "443"

    Id_source_asg = "0"
    Id_destination_asg = "1"

    Id_nsg = "0"
    },]

I didn't wrote everything in purpose in my main post, that's normal there is more values there

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do the following:

```
source_application_security_group_ids = [for elem in var.nsgrule_asg_asg[count.index]["Id_source_asg"]: element(azurerm_application_security_group.asg.*.id, elem.Id_nsg)],
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,

I got this error : 

var.nsgrule_asg_asg is list of object with 10 elements

A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.

Comment: @TontonJuju Can you show the actual example of the `var.nsgrule_asg_asg`?

Comment: sure, this is an example (sorry it seems to be in one block there in the comment) : 

nsgrule_asg_asg = [
    {
    access = "Allow"
    rule_sufix = "infra"
    nsg-rule_rg = "rgp..."
    ...

    Id_source_asg = "0"
    Id_destination_asg = "1"
    Id_nsg = "0"
    },
]

Comment: @TontonJuju I updated the answer, but if still does not work, then probably would have to update the question with all the actual variable values and any full error messages.

Comment: I updated my answer, still not working, same error . Maybe because I don't give the values in the good way  in my tfvars file.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to read carefully is the parameters of the function [element()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/element.html):

> The index is zero-based. This function produces an error if used with
> an empty list. The index must be a non-negative integer.

The index must be a non-negative integer. But the parameter `Id_source_asg` in the `variable nsgrule_asg_asg` is a string. So you need to change the type into integer. Then everything can work well.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, 
Yes I know element() wants an integer for its index. My question is that I want to retrive multiple ressource ids using element() . Maybe by using a for before the element, I have to try it

Comment: @TontonJuju If you only need the NSG id, why not directly use the function like this `element(azurerm_application_security_group.asg.*.id, count.index)`? Anything you want to specify?

Comment: This is working perfeclty fine for one asg id in my rule.
There, I want to have multiple asg ids in my rule

Comment: @TontonJuju One NSG rule for multiple asg ids? Or what?

Comment: Multiple ASG ids for one NSG rule (you can do it manualy in the portal).
And my NSG is composed of multiple NSG rules

Comment: @TontonJuju Do you mean you want to create one NSG with multiple rules? So how do you create one rule with multiple asg ids? each rule?

Comment: "Do you mean you want to create one NSG with multiple rules?" --> Yes that's right , my script is doing that.
"But So how do you create one rule with multiple asg ids? each rule?" -> It's my question , that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @TontonJuju If each rule need to assign with all the asg ids, you just need to give the list, no element function.

Comment: I have a list of 6 ASG (so index 0 to 5) . For one rule I need the 0,1,2 and for an other I need the 3,4,5. That's why I use the element function, to be able the select the asg id I want.

Comment: @TontonJuju Do you mean you need to create two rules, and each rule has three asg ids?

Comment: it's a module, I can't predict how many NSG rules or ASGs inside a rule  I will have to use

Comment: @TontonJuju If you don't know how many asgs inside a rule. then it's impossible to achieve what you want. You have to plan all the things before coding.

Comment: I mean, today I have a Rule with 3 asg but tomorrow people can ask me to have 4 ASG in this rule or add more rules in my nsg. That's why I want a flexible code.

Comment: @TontonJuju You can use a list for the asgs that need to assign the rule. And add the elements of the list if you want later. Give the list to the attribute `source_application_security_group_ids`. It requires a list of the ASG ids.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get rid of this problem by stopping using indexs in my code. Now I use for_each and key/values and now It's working better.

To retrive multiple ids with names I use
`[for k, v in azurerm_application_security_group.asg : v.id if contains(each.value.source_asg_list, v.name)]`